# Is it possible to find out what email address is associated to a YouTube channel if "View Email Address" isn't there?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

I'm trying to access my business YouTube channel and do not know the email address associated with it. The channel was set up by a previous employee and we have no idea what they used. How can I gain access to it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. This question doesn't include enough details, and it looks like a troubleshooting question that this site is not well suited to deal with kind of questions. You might [edit] the question to add more details, but you might better get familiar with [Sign up and manage your account | YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/topic/9267757?hl=en) first.